# Excel VBA Macro to add a blank row when the value in column A is 1

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to add a row in excel vba when ever the value in column A is 1, here is the code I wrote, but this returns a "subscript out of range error". What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub InsertRow()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Col = "A"
        StartRow = 1
        LastRow = 20
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            For R = StartRow To LastRow
                If Cells(R, Col) = 1 Then
                Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End If
            Next R

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: will you be adding the blank row after the one containing 1?

Comment: That **shouldn't** give a "subscript out of range" error, but it also won't do what you want.  (You probably want `For R = LastRow To StartRow Step -1`, and possibly `Cells(R+1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown`)

Comment: What line gives the "subscript out of range" error?  I was assuming it was something to do with the loop - but is it actually on your `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate` statement?  That would imply you don't have a sheet called "Sheet1".

Comment: @SEarle1986  : I have sheet with numbers in column A and some other values in the remaining columns, if the number in col A is 1 then I have insert a row above that

Comment: @YowE3K : My bad, you are right. I thought internally all the sheets would be named as Sheet1 et. Any ways thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Code below tested and works.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim cntr as Long
    For cntr = 20 to 5 Step - 1
          If .Cells(cntr, 1) = 1 Then .cells(cntr,1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next

End With
```

Comment: Which line @goog?. Do you have  worksheet called `Sheet1`? If not, modified that name to fit your actual tab in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub InsertRow()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Col = "A"
    StartRow = 1
    LastRow = 20
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    R = StartRow
    Do While R <= LastRow
        If Cells(R, Col) = 1 Then
            Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            R = R + 1
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
        End If
        R = R + 1
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note the setting of the value of R in the loop, as you are shifting the rows down, you are continually checking the same value and therefore adding a row each time so we need to increment R by 1 to skip past the 1 we just checked.

We also need to change the endpoint as we are pushing values past Row 20 by inserting so we also increment the LastRow variable. We cannot do this in a for loop in VBA, the for loop will terminate at 20 so I have changed to a while loop

As per the comment below, working backwards from 20 is far more elequent but since I didn't think of that I haven't put it in here :)

Comment: You would also need to extend the loop a few more iterations.  E.g. If every second row had 1, you would only insert 5 new rows.

Comment: Note: It's much easier just to use `For R = LastRow To StartRow Step -1` ;)